# Почему у двух div-елементов top отсчитывается от разных точек?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При написании змейки на JS возникла проблема: у двух дивов, обозначающих змейку(зел) и яблоко(крас), top отсчитывается от разных точек. С чем это связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот CSS код:

```
#sn{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: #0F440F;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
#app{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#area{
    outline: 4px solid #805100;
    outline-offset: -4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #28BB28;
}
```

Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: не relative а absolute надо - realtive это относительное позиционирование и фактически не меняет расположение на странице

Comment: спасибо, замена на абсолют помогла, но вот хотелось бы знать, почему у двух одинаковых дивов с одним родителем разные точки отсчета. мб это связано с порядком добавления, или они зависят друг от друга, или что то другое?

Comment: в случае с релейтив*

Comment: @ВоваСедько, relative считает top и left от позиции элемента, которую он занимал бы с position:static

Comment: проверил на static и всё сразу стало ясно. Яблоко отсчитывало от змейки. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идеи вам поможет:

```
#area {
  position: relative;
}

#app, #sn {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: в моем случае помогла замена значений только последних двух, спасибо

Comment: Если Вам помогло - пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ полезным. :)

Comment: репы не хватает, но пишет, что приняло. как наберу отмечу ещё раз

Comment: Про репу не понял ) Вроде все отметилось. Спасибо. )

Comment: @cracken кстати, id в CSS-селекторах имеет высший приоритет... если потом захочется этому элементу добавить стили через другой класс, этот класс не перебьет ранее написанный стиль для Id... поэтому принято использовать классы для стилей, а id - для JS.

Comment: спасибо, заменю